# Android : how to read XML data in URL

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, augmented-reality

I want to read XML data from URL and have tried in different ways. But unable to find the answer. Iam developing a agumented reality application, where iam reading location information from XML ( which is in URL )

Iam new bee to android as well

I have the following XML data.

```
<specialoffers>
<categories>
<category>
      <![CDATA[ 0% Installment Payment Plan Offers ]]>
</category>
<merchants>
     <merchantname>
             <![CDATA[ EmaxIPP ]]>
     </merchantname>
     <merchantbigimage>
             <![CDATA[
             http://www.XXX.com/Images/Emax%20New%20-%20190x73-1_tcm20-48180.jpg      
      ]]>
     </merchantbigimage>
     <merchantsmallimage>
             <![CDATA[
             http://www.XXX.com/Images/Emax%20New%20-%20104x75-1_tcm20-48179.jpg
              ]]>
             </merchantsmallimage>
     <merchantmobileimage>
             <![CDATA[ http://www.XXX.com ]]>
     </merchantmobileimage>
     <mobilehighlight>
             <![CDATA[
            Enjoy 0% Installment Payment Plan for 3 months on 
            all purchases made </b>
            ]]>
     </mobilehighlight>
     <highlight>
            <![CDATA[
            Enjoy 0% Installment Payment Plan for 3 months on all purchases
            made with  your </b>
            ]]>
      </highlight>
     <locations>
          <location>
               <emirate>
                   <![CDATA[ XXX]]>
               </emirate>
               <address>
                   <![CDATA[ Center 1 ]]>
               </address>
               <latitude>
                   <![CDATA[ 51.169601 ]]>
              </latitude>
              <longitude>
                   <![CDATA[ 61.240395 ]]>
              </longitude>
          </location>
     </merchants>

   </categories>
</specialoffers>
```

Here is the code....

AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://www.adcb.com/specialoffers-test.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "categories"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "category";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = 
                                 new ArrayList<HashMap<String,   String>>();

XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML

Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
// looping through all item nodes <item>
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    menuItems.add(map);
}

// Adding menuItems to ListView
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
        R.layout.list_item,
        new String[] { KEY_ID, "KEY_DESC", "100" }, new int[] {
                R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });

setListAdapter(adapter);

// selecting single ListView item
ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem
        String name = ((TextView)  
                                  view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        String cost = ((TextView) 
                                   view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
        String description = ((TextView)
                              view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  
                                    SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(KEY_ID, name);
        in.putExtra("100", cost);
        in.putExtra("KEY_DESC", description);
        startActivity(in);

    }
});
}
}
```

XMLParser.java

```
public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child =   
child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

SingleMenuItemActivity.java

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ID = "category";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ID);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DESC);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);

    lblName.setText(name);
    lblCost.setText(cost);
    lblDesc.setText(description);
}
}
```

Comment: More important than the structure of your xml is how you're trying to read it. Show us so precious time is not wasted telling you what you already know or have tried.

Comment: Can anyone provide the related source code, it would be really helpful to me.

Comment: accept any answer that helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can use xmlpullparser like this :

```
XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I found a link demonstrating the same example as per your need.Please go through this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/)

Or just go the android way . A developer guide [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleXml](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#optional) xml parsing API for android it'll make your coding easy.